# How is the rotation symmetry group of the square rectangular cuboid isomorphic to the symmetry group of the square?

Tags: group-theory, permutations, finite-groups, symmetric-groups

By a "square rectangular cuboid", I mean this particular shape...

[image]
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxcKDm.jpg): https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxcKDm.jpg

...made of two squares and four rectangles. Also known as a square rectangular parallelpiped.

Define the group $G$ to be strictly the rotational symmetry group of this above shape. As far as I'm aware, there are only three axes of symmetry (the x, y and z axes). If we take the vertical axis to be the y-axis, then (correct me if I'm wrong) there are y-axis rotations by $90^{\circ}$, $180^{\circ}$, $270^{\circ}$ and $360^{\circ}=\mathbf{1}$. About the x axis there is a $180^\circ$ rotation and $\mathbf{1}$ for the $360^\circ$ rotation, and similarly for the z-axis rotations we have the same thing, a $180^\circ$ rotation and $\mathbf{1}$ for the $360^\circ$ rotation. So this group appears to have order 6 (omitting the repeated $\mathbf{1}$ elements obviously).

I have read that this is isomorphic to the entire symmetry group of the square which includes both rotations and reflections. However, that group has order 8, so since a group isomorphism has to include a bijection, I don't see how this can be true.

Is there something I'm missing here or not understanding?

Comment: You've neglected the reflections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on the comment—you're missing the elements of the rotational symmetry group that are the composition of a 180° rotation about the $x$ or $z$ axis and a 90° rotation about the $y$ axis.

To see the group isomorphism intuitively, you can think about identifying the vertical edges of length $c$ in this figure with the vertices of a square. By extruding the vertices of the square into edges, the reflections in the square's symmetry group become the 180° rotations about the $x$ and $z$ axes in this figure's rotational symmetry group.