# Symmetry group of rectangular cuboid

Tags: group-theory, symmetry

In [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuboid) it is said that the symmetry group of the rectangular cuboid (a box with three unequal dimensions) is a dihedral group $D_8$ (well, some people may call it $D_4$...)
[image]

However, I don't see how it is the case. If the symmetry group is $D_8$, there is a rotation element $r$ that has order $4$, i.e., $r^4=e$, but there is no such element in the symmetry group of the rectangular cuboid that has order $4$. Every element in the symmetry group of the rectangular cuboid seems to have order $2$ (except for the identity, of course) and I think it should be $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2$.

Is there anything I misunderstand here?

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4148089/104041) appears not to be a duplicate.

Comment: We can check in GAP.

Comment: Label the corners $1$ through $8$. Make a note of what the generators do. Plug those permutations into GAP. See what group comes out

Comment: If you color the sides it would work...

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: @leslietownes (+1) Maybe post as an answer for posterity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct.

If you label the vertices $1$ through to $8$, like so . . .

[image: A rectangular cuboid with the top, front left labelled 1; top, back left labelled 2; top, back right labelled 3; top, front right labelled 4; front, bottom right labelled 5; back, bottom right labelled 6; back, bottom left labelled 7; and the remaining, 8.]

. . . you get the generators:

$$\begin{align}
a&=(17)(28)(35)(46),\\
b&=(13)(24)(57)(68),\\
c&=(15)(48)(26)(37),\\
x&=(14)(23)(58)(67),\\
y&=(18)(27)(36)(45),\\
z&=(12)(34)(56)(78).
\end{align}$$

Putting this in GAP, we get:

```
gap> G:=Group([(1,7)*(2,8)*(3,5)*(4,6), (1,3)*(2,4)*(5,7)*(6,8), (1,5)*(4,8)*(2,6)*(3,7), (1,4)*(2,3)*(5,8)*(6,7), (1,8)*(2,7)*(3,6)*(4,5), (1,2)*(3,4)*(5,6)*(7,8)]);
Group([ (1,7)(2,8)(3,5)(4,6), (1,3)(2,4)(5,7)(6,8), (1,5)(2,6)(3,7)(4,8), (1,4)(2,3)(5,8)(6,7), (1,8)(2,7)(3,6)(4,5), (1,2)(3,4)(5,6)(7,8) ])
gap> StructureDescription(G);
"C2 x C2 x C2"
gap>
```

This confirms your intuition.

---

You can confirm through direct calculation that the elements commute and each have order two. That is sufficient to conclude that it is indeed $\Bbb Z_2^3$ (as there is eight elements in total).

Comment: Someone keeps editing the Wikipedia page back to what it was, so I suspect I might be wrong.

Comment: Yeah... I don't know why people take it to be a dihedral group.

Comment: +1 but you shouldn't need gap to see the eight symmetries and how they multiply geometrically.

Comment: Are you sure it's right, @EthanBolker? The people at Wikipedia seem adamant it's the dihedral group. I mean: I'm doubting myself a lot but I don't see any mistakes in what I have written here.

Comment: I *was* sure . . .

Comment: @Shaun You're right. Hard to know what to do about wikipedia. The error is in the sidebar, not the text, so you can't simply offer the argument that there is no symmetry of order four. Maybe write this answer into the text and then edit the sidebar too. Then someone would have to revert the whole argument.

Comment: See the nice answer here from @leslietownes .

Answer (score 3):

[Reposting my comment as an answer, per request in the comments]

I believe this apparent discrepancy is just a difference in notation, i.e., that what Wikipedia identifies as "$D_{2h}$" is indeed the abstract group $\mathbb{Z_2} \times \mathbb{Z_2} \times \mathbb{Z_2}$.

In particular, Wikipedia's "$D_{2h}$" may not be notation for the dihedral group of order $2h$ (or indeed any dihedral group), but Schoenflies notation, in which "$D_{kh}$," where $k$ is a parameter and $h$ is a decoration peculiar to this notation, is a group described in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schoenflies_notation (describing both "$D_n$" and "$D_{nh}$," and note that the latter is not just the former with $n$ replaced by $nh$).

As I interpret this description (which is admittedly somewhat opaque without a lot of background geometrical context), it looks as though "$D_{kh}$" as "defined" there is generally a group of order $4k$, and not necessarily the dihedral group of that order.  Indeed, it seems possible that the somewhat vague verbal recipe for "$D_{kh}$" given on that Wikipedia page, if formalized more concretely via generators and relations, might lead to exactly the presentation that Shaun's answer identifies (or at least something close to it, and giving rise to the same abstract group) in the case $k=2$.

In partial confirmation of my interpretation, the Schoenflies notation is also used in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystallographic_point_group, in particular in a table in the section labeled "Isomorphisms," which identifies "$D_{2h}$" as "$D_2 \times C_2$," where $C_2$ is elsewhere identified on that page as the cyclic group of order $2$ and "$D_2$" is elsewhere identified as the Klein 4-group (i.e., $C_2 \times C_2$, which is indeed the dihedral group of order $4$).  More succinctly, this table identifies the group "$D_{2h}$" with $C_2 \times C_2 \times C_2$, as expected.

Comment: +1 thank you. Can you edit the wikipedia page that confused the OP to make this point there?

Comment: @EthanBolker Oh, good point. I do not edit Wikipedia, but a fix seems simple enough that maybe someone else can implement?  [At the moment, the link for "$D_{2h}$" in the table on the "Cuboid" page points to Wikipedia's page for "Dihedral symmetry." and this linking is likely the source of all confusion, as the "Dihedral symmetry" page does not use Schoenflies notation and uses the symbol scheme $D_x$ for something else.  If the "$D_{2h}$" link on "Cuboid" pointed instead to the Wikipedia page for Schoenflies notation, this potential source of confusion would vanish.]